# AttributeError: module 'diffsptk' has no attribute 'read'

Tags: pytorch

I want to use **diffsptk** module in Google Colab.

Its website provides sample codes.
https://github.com/sp-nitech/diffsptk

I finished installing it and tried the same code as it provides.

```
import diffsptk

# Set analysis condition.
fl = 400
fp = 80
n_fft = 512
M = 24

# Read waveform.
x, sr = diffsptk.read("assets/data.wav")
```

However, the last line got an error,
`AttributeError: module 'diffsptk' has no attribute 'read'`

What can I do to use "read" function?

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-730b9b2e9ac2> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x, sr = diffsptk.read(wavname)

AttributeError: module 'diffsptk' has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: What is your script's name?

Comment: @ewokx Thank you for your comment. Excuse me but what is the "script's name"? I use python notebook and the python version is Python 3.9.16. Is this what you asked?

Comment: What is the filename that you put the above code in?

Comment: It's `test_01.ipynb`

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-730b9b2e9ac2> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x, sr = diffsptk.read(wavname)

AttributeError: module 'diffsptk' has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Please include that in your post.

Comment: @ewokx I am really sorry after you started helping me, but after I uninstalled the **diffsptk** module and installed it again, it works(=problem was solved).

Comment: OK, I should have included the full traceback error in my post itself. Thank you for your advice